# Execute Another Spider with Selenium via Scrapy Item Pipeline

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

hope you guys can help me with this as I'm kinda new to scrapy/web scraping in general and not really sure on how to proceed forward with this problem.

Essentially, I have 2 spiders:

- `audio_file_downloader_spider`, This spider is going to:

  - check whether a particular webpage passed to it contains an audio file (**.mp3**/**.wav**, etc.)
  - Suppose that an audio file URL is found on the webpage, download the audio file to the local machine.
  - Suppose that there is NO audio file URL found on the webpage, please  tell `audio_recorder_spider` to scrape the webpage
- `audio_recorder_spider`, is going to use selenium chromedriver and it will:

  - Press the audio player **play** button on the webpage
  - Record the playback stream to an mp3 file (this is definitely doable)

Now... the problem I'm currently facing is..., how do we do something like this with scrapy?

Currently, I have both spiders ready and I can run the  `audio_file_downloader_spider` with this command from the terminal (I'm using macOS):

```
scrapy crawl audio_file_downloader_spider \
-a url="<some_webpage_url>"
```

Now, I need to somehow tell scrapy to execute `audio_recorder_spider` on the same webpage url IF and ONLY IF there is no audio file URL detected on the webpage so that `audio_recorder_spider` can record the audio playback on the webpage.

Now I'm not too familiar with scrapy just yet but I did read the their item pipeline documentation. One of the examples they gave in their documentation shows a code which will automatically get a screenshot off of a URL using Splash and save that screenshot as a PNG file with a custom name. The code can be seen below:

```
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import quote

import scrapy
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.utils.defer import maybe_deferred_to_future


class ScreenshotPipeline:
    """Pipeline that uses Splash to render screenshot of
    every Scrapy item."""

    SPLASH_URL = "http://localhost:8050/render.png?url={}"

    async def process_item(self, item, spider):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        encoded_item_url = quote(adapter["url"])
        screenshot_url = self.SPLASH_URL.format(encoded_item_url)
        request = scrapy.Request(screenshot_url)
        response = await maybe_deferred_to_future(spider.crawler.engine.download(request, spider))

        if response.status != 200:
            # Error happened, return item.
            return item

        # Save screenshot to file, filename will be hash of url.
        url = adapter["url"]
        url_hash = hashlib.md5(url.encode("utf8")).hexdigest()
        filename = f"{url_hash}.png"
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        # Store filename in item.
        adapter["screenshot_filename"] = filename
        return item
```

So this got me thinking, would it be possible to do the same thing but instead of using Splash and taking a screenshot of the webpage, I want to use Selenium and record the audio playback off of the URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I would rather run first only `audio_file_downloader_spider` with full CPU power (if it is possible) and write urls in file, and later I would run `audio_recorder_spider` with full CPU power and read urls from file.

Comment: evetually I would run both at the same time (started separatelly) and use some `queue` to send urls from one program to another. Something similar to [How can I make start_url in scrapy to consume from a message queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966941/how-can-i-make-start-url-in-scrapy-to-consume-from-a-message-queue)

Comment: @furas, 

Mate thanks for replying :) 

Right I see, yeah that's actually something I've been thinking as well, basically just writing URLs that don't have any audio file URL in its HTML and just save that URL to a file. However, this is the first time I've heard something about scrapy consuming URL from a message queue, thanks so much for the link! 

**EDIT: I still do want to know if there's a direct way of executing the selenium crawler/spider from item pipeline directly though or if there's a cleaner way of doing this just with scrapy.**

Comment: you can try to run to run other spider using `scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess` directly from your code. You can see code in my answer [Scrapy doesn't print anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476860/scrapy-doesnt-print-anything/71478208?noredirect=1#comment126360583_71478208) . It uses `CrawlerProcess` to start spider without using `scrapy crawl`

Comment: @furas, 

Yeah basically just use the scrapy `crawler` API instead of running the spider from the command line. That's definitely worth a try. Again, thanks heaps mate! I'll try to play around with this a bit~

Comment: in documentation you can see page [Common Practices](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html). It shows `Run Scrapy from a script` and `Running multiple spiders in the same process`

Comment: @furas, 

Yeah I did read that part of the documentation about using crawler API and using `CrawlerProcess`. As a matter of fact, one of the spiders I used the `CrawlerProcess` for one of the spiders I created. I suppose then I need some kind of `if - else` statement or a `try-except` block to catch URLs where the audio file URL is not available on the webpage and then execute the other spider inside the control flow block. Hmmm, not really sure how to that . This is the problem when you have someone like me just starting using scrapy not too long ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243009/discussion-between-blue2609-and-furas).